# Correctly configure Samba

Tags: network-shares, samba, arch-linux, file-permissions

I'm trying to set up samba on my arch arm box, for shares that I can access from various places but I can't seem to get it right;

What I'm after is the following:

Users:

1. Log-in with system user acccounts
2. Users get their home directory
3. Users get the media directory
4. Users get read/write to media directory

Guest:

1. Guest is restricted to media directory
2. Guest gets read only of media directory

Root:

1. Root starts in /
2. Root gets read/write

For some reason, the shareuser can see the root directory, so i set valid user to root, but then i can't log in to it even with root account.

I'm not too up on this Samba stuff so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want root to have access to the whole file-tree, add a share [everything] with path = / and use that instead of setting root's home directory to /. For the media folder to be writable, add a group called sambausers (or use an existing group) and add users to that group with `usermod -a -G sambausers username`. You will have to check that the shared path has group write permissions enabled (chmod 775 /path/media).

**/etc/samba/smb.conf** (significant parts)

```
[global]
   security = user

[media]
      comment = Media folder
      path = /mnt/media
      #valid users = jaroslav
      public = yes
      read only = yes
      guest ok = yes
      guest account = nobody
      write list = @sambausers
      printable = no
      browseable = yes

[homes]
      comment = Home Directories
      browseable = no
      writable = yes
```